# How to create root organization profile?

Tags: organization-profile

Anybody know how can I add a root organization profile? I have following issue:

- I did not have any organization profile

[image]

- I created a new profile

[image]

- I tried to add a child organization profile, but got error

[image]

[image]

I looked at SharePoint log and found that the OrganizationProfileManager.RootOrganization property is null.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I simply created new profile service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a full userprofile import first. Normally u should have an default organization profile called "root organization", in my opinion it is not necessary to create it by your own.

Don't use the Configuration wizzard to create your User Profile Synchronization, do it manually:

[Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)

Greets